# How to generate menu item on laravel-admin.org?

Tags: php, laravel, command, admin, laravel-admin

I found this topic: [laravel-admin.org generate menu command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62733381/laravel-admin-org-generate-menu-command-line)
But the issue was not resolved. How do I create a menu item, via code or command?
so that I can share the result with a friend via git.
If there is no solution, i will have to write a seeder.
Its very popular extension, and i cannot find an answer to a simple question. Please help me.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D12In.png)

Answer (score 0):

I made migration:

```
    public function up()
{
    /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $menuModel */
    $menuModel = config('admin.database.menu_model');
    $menuModel::create([
        'parent_id' => 0,
        'order'     => 0,
        'title'     => 'Settings',
        'icon'      => 'fa-gears',
        'uri'       => '/settings'
    ]);
}
```